# nested razor and c-code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, syntax

The solution seems simple enough but i just cant figure out!

I have nested code in razor:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      @foreach (MapDetail geMapDetail in Model.mapDetails)
      {
        if (geMapDetail.Growth.Equals(true))
        {
         var firstColumn = @geMapDetail.RowOrder - 1;
         var secondColumn = @geMapDetail.RowOrder - 2;

         //string fullHeader;


         //System.Collections.IEnumerable<bool> growthCols = Model.mapDetails.Select(md => md.RowOrder == firstColumn || md.RowOrder == secondColumn).ToList();



         <th id=@geMapDetail.MapDetailID>Growth @firstColumn - secondColumn</th>    
        }
        else if (geMapDetail.EffectSize == true)
        {
             var firstColumn = @geMapDetail.RowOrder - 1;
                        var secondColumn = @geMapDetail.RowOrder - 2;

                        <th id=@geMapDetail.MapDetailID>EffectSize @firstColumn - @secondColumn</th>
        }
     }
    </tr>
 </thead>
```

Now when i want to uncomment

```
 //    System.Collections.IEnumerable<bool> growthCols = Model.mapDetails.Select(md => md.RowOrder == firstColumn || md.RowOrder == secondColumn).ToList();
```

Everything goes out of order.

My second question is, i expect IEnumerable object but i have to put bool otherwise there is a casting issue..

this is not working

```
Select.ToList<MapDetail>()
```

**UPDATE**

I have replaced Select with Where as suggested by Stephen

```
System.Collections.IEnumerable<MapDetail>() growthCols = Model.mapDetails.Where<MapDetail>(md => md.RowOrder == firstColumn || md.RowOrder == secondColumn).ToList();
```

want a collection of MapDetail from the Model.mapDetails and i will then use it to traverse each datarow in the collection growthcols so i can get their name i.e. **growthCols[0].Name** and **growthCols[1].Name** then the  that follows will use these names

Comment: You meant `Select` or `Where` ?

Comment: If you want `growthCols` to be a collection of `geMapDetail` then it needs to be a `Where()` clause. But how do you want to use that filtered collection?

Comment: yes i want a collection of MapDetail from the Model.mapDetails and i will then use it to traverse each datarow in the collection growthcols so i can get their name i.e. growthCols[0].Name and growthCols[1].Name then the <th> that follows will use these names